# restart of tomcat makes application faster

Tags: java, tomcat

We have hosted our java application in Linux server. We developed an java application using Spring Boot framework where we have used postgresql 9.5.15 as database. Java,tomcat and postgresql are installed in the linux server.  We deployed our war file in the linux server. Initially the application runs fine and as time passes by the application gets slower. We checked the resources at that time and found out that some time cpu usage becomes high and other resources are normal. Also sometime outgoing traffic exceed 8 Mbps . The form load and other process get slower. Once the tomcat is restarted, then everything comes to normal. Application again becomes faster. We are unable to find out the problem. Is there any tomcat setting that can make our application run faster. Cpu usage graph is shown below:[image].

Comment: There are many things that could cause this ... including flaws in your system architecture or bugs in your code.  My suggestion would be to profile Tomcat while it is running slowly, and see if that gves you some clues.  There may also be clues in `jstack` output / a thread stack dump.   (Or in your log file.)

Comment: *"Also log file in tomcat has increased to 5 Gb."* - Don't ask multiple questions in one Question.  Delete this ... and ask a separate Question (after researching it!!).

Comment: what  are the things i need  to profile tomcat?

Comment: A cpu utilization profiler.  Try googling "java profiling".

Comment: If you have a request that is slow, e.g. runs a large query, the request continues to be processed and takes up resources, even if the client has stopped waiting on the response. --- E.g. if a page is slow, the user might press F5 to refresh the page, maybe even multiple times. Now the server is processing those multiple requests in parallel, even though the client is only waiting on the last one. All those "orphan" requests, taking up processing power, are discarded when you restart Tomcat. To check if that's the case, check pending requests.

Comment: how can i check the pending requests

Comment: @ManiRatna _"Also log file in tomcat has increased to 5 Gb."_ It could be that this is one of the reasons for slowness. Hence, I suggest that first this be solved.

When writing to large files, CPU utilization does go high. Turning off debug logging to files, using rolling file appenders, etc. can reduce this problem drastically.